# How to make edge sloped on a cylinder?

Tags: blender, 3d-modelling

I'm beginner at 3D modelling and I'm making an office chair. Now I'm stuck at wheel area as I need a sloped edge cylinder for the base of the wheel.

Concept: The wheel is attached to a cylindrical base which is attached to the foot of the chair.

Current Situation: I draw foot of chair, made a circle on it and transformed into a cylinder. The end edge of the cylinder has no Face and I want to extrude the cylinder along one edge which will make a sloped area on the open side of area. That should look like this :
[image]

But I tried manythings to do, but failed. It's obvious as I said I'm beginner. Please help me do to this.

Note: I'm using blender 2.78

Comment: who put a negative vote on question!

Answer (score 1):

The [shear tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/shear.html) will move your mesh the way you want. It doesn't create the geometry so first extrude <kbd>E</kbd> and then shear <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> the extruded section. Also note that the shear tool always uses the viewport axis, so switch to front or side view to keep the movement in line with your object.

You could also extrude past the point you want and use the [knife](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife_subdivide.html) or [bisect](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/bisect.html) tool to cut the geometry at the angle you want.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. This doesn't need complex techniques. I just did
Extrude > Merge > At the First.

That's it. Now I got the shape I wanted.